# How to fix my building tree function. If parent ID doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, json

I'm setting up a build a tree function. All works fine till I add a document with a parentID that doesn't exist. The root node should also be the smallest paarentID. Even if the parentID is not "0". I can't figures out what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried to add an if clause somewhere, but I didn't have success.

```
function list_to_tree(list) {
          var map = {},
            node,
            roots = [],
            i;




          for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {

            map[list[i]._id] = i; // initialize the map

            list[i].children = []; // initialize the children
            list[i].link = []; // initialize the link field
          }



          for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
            node = list[i];

            if (node._source.parentID !== '0') {

                    list[map[node._source.parentID]].children.push(node);

            } else {
              roots.push(node);
            }
          }
          return roots;


        }

        var entries = [

          {
            "_index": "fud_alvr",
            "_type": "analyse",
            "_id": "10",
            "_score": 1.4142135,
            "_source": {
              "ID": "10",
              "parentID": "0",
              "content": "Europa"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "fud_alvr",
            "_type": "analyse",
            "_id": "22",
            "_score": 1.4142135,
            "_source": {
              "ID": "22",
              "parentID": "10",
              "content": "Germany"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "fud_alvr",
            "_type": "analyse",
            "_id": "23",
            "_score": 1.4142135,
            "_source": {
              "ID": "23",
              "parentID": "90",
              "content": "Switzerland"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "fud_alvr",
            "_type": "analyse",
            "_id": "438",
            "_score": 1.4142135,
            "_source": {
              "ID": "438",
              "parentID": "22",
              "content": "München"
            }
          }

        ];
         console.log(list_to_tree(entries));
```

Error message is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

if I delete Switzerland all work well.

Comment: what should happen with unknow `parentID`? should it assigned to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the parent exists and if not assign `'0'` as `parentID`.

```js
function list_to_tree(list) {
  var map = {},
    node,
    roots = [],
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    map[list[i]._id] = i; // initialize the map
    list[i].children = []; // initialize the children
    list[i].link = []; // initialize the link field
  }

  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    node = list[i];

    // check if parent exists
    if (!(node._source.parentID in map)) node._source.parentID = '0';

    if (node._source.parentID !== '0') {
      list[map[node._source.parentID]].children.push(node);
    } else {
      roots.push(node);
    }
  }
  return roots;
}

var entries = [{ _index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "10", _score: 1.4142135, _source: { ID: "10", parentID: "0", content: "Europa" } }, { _index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "22", _score: 1.4142135, _source: { ID: "22", parentID: "10", content: "Germany" } }, { _index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "23", _score: 1.4142135, _source: { ID: "23", parentID: "90", content: "Switzerland" } }, { _index: "fud_alvr", _type: "analyse", _id: "438", _score: 1.4142135, _source: { ID: "438", parentID: "22", content: "München" } }];

console.log(list_to_tree(entries));
```

Comment: thx Nina!! do you also know how to sort each node by the field "content" alphabetically?

Comment: you could sort the array in advance or later, but with first, you need only a single sorting.